# How to check request is POST or GET in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to check the request from webpage to Android Device, `whether it is POST request or GET request as in Google Chrome browser`.  Please any tell me how to do it.

[image]

**Note:** I want to check like below in any of the `WebView's Override method`.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    do_something()
elif request.method == 'POST':
    do_something_else()
```

**EDIT 1:** I have tried to login into Google. I got "POST" as below. I have tried this with Android WebView used the method onFormResubmission. But not called.

```
@Override
public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend) {          
    super.onFormResubmission(view, dontResend, resend);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: so you are using an Android webview and everytime you press "enter" you wanna know if is it a Get or Post requests?

Comment: yes blackbelt. But not pressing enter, for every url is loaded in webview, that time i want to check

Comment: What is the solution ?
i also want to know once the page is finished that whether it is GET or POST...

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String reqMethod = con.getRequestMethod();
```

In this way you can get the exact method

Answer (score 0):

use custom [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onFormResubmission%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.os.Message,%20android.os.Message%29) as bellow

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this){

        @Override
        public void loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding) {
            Log.d("TAGloadData", data+" ==> "+mimeType+" "+encoding);
            super.loadData(data, mimeType, encoding);
        }

        @Override
        public void loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders) {
            Log.d("TAGloadUrl", " ==> "+extraHeaders);
            super.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);

        }

        @Override
        public void loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data,
                String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl) {
            Log.d("TAGloadUrlB", " ==> "+data);
            super.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, mimeType, encoding, historyUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void loadUrl(String url) {

            if(!url.startsWith("method"))
                Log.d("TAGForm", " ==> using Post method");
            else{
                url = url.replaceFirst("method","");
                Log.d("TAGForm", " ==> using Get method"+url);
            }

            super.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d("TAGloadUrl", " ==> "+url);
        }

    };
```

Comment: i think resubmission is only is you resubmit a form (like a reload or a back or something)

Comment: I can get "POST" while checking with Google Chrome Broswer. But it is not working with device. If post is comming then onFormReSubmission, not called